# How to display input field "name" on the label

Tags: html, css

I have an input to upload an image and a label that displays on top of the input.
The reason I add the label on top of the input is so I can display the style what I want and add custom text.

In the input (if you remove the css, display: none; for #uploadImg), there's a field "name", that displays no file chosen and when an image is uploaded, it's going to show the name of the image.

However, when I do "display: none" the input, the "name" field also dissapeares.
Is there a way we can show the "name" field? I tried to add label name="uploadImg"
But doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to show the name field input when it's display is none? If not, how to fix this?

```css
.upload {
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#uploadImg {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="upload" for="uploadImg">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadImg" id="uploadImg" value="test" accept=".jpg,.png">
```

Comment: Try to add visibility: hidden; Then the input isnt shown but everything will be there

Comment: @ViLuWi When I add visibility: hidden, it's also hides the input and name field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add some javascript to help you with this task, add a span with a class then add onchange in your input like that

```
<label class="upload" for="uploadImg">Upload Image</label>
<span class="fileName">No file chosen</span>
<input type="file" name="uploadImg" id="uploadImg" onchange="fileChanged(this)" 
value="test" accept=".jpg,.png">
```

then add some javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fileChanged(input) {
    let fileName = document.querySelector('.fileName');
    fileName.textContent = input.files[0]['name'];
  }
</script>
```

your CSS dont have to change!

Comment: Seems like the only solution is Javascript, as there seems to be no way to hide not the complete input.